# Stored procedure split by separator and Match Record to get

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I use SQL Server 2014 platform. I have created a stored procedure which I pass 2 parameter to: `Die` and `MetalCode`.

If `MetalCode` is Null or blank, then if part will execute but when `MetalCode` has any type of value, then else part will execute in which I have to create loop to split value by `|`.

Here is my table structure

[Table Structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyd3e.png)

Here is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TDCwax_Get_TDCNo]
    @Die NVARCHAR(15),
    @MetalCode INT,
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TDC NVARCHAR(15)
    DECLARE @TDCMetal NVARCHAR(80)
    DECLARE @TDCNo NVARCHAR(15), @yield DECIMAL(5,2), @Asswt DECIMAL(7,3)

    SELECT
        @TDC = TDCNO, @TDCMetal = ISNULL(TDCMCode, '') 
    FROM
        TDCWax  
    WHERE
        Mouldcode = @Die 
        AND Status = 1 
    ORDER BY 
        TdcMCode DESC

    IF @TDCMetal = Null OR @TDCMetal = ''
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            @TDCNo = TDCNo, @yield = Yield, @Asswt = AssemblyWT 
        FROM
            TDCWax 
        WHERE
            MouldCode = @Die AND Status = 1

        PRINT @TDCNo
        PRINT @yield
        PRINT @Asswt
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @TDCMcode TABLE (TdcMcode INT)

        @TDCMcode = Split(@TDCMetal, '|')

        -- What I have to do right here
        -- @TDCMetal=25|35|65|22  ----- This String Split And Compare Parameter Pass @MetalCode Then Equal 
    END
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [SQL split functions](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-t-sql-split-function.aspx) custom build by community developers if you are using a SQL Server version prior to SQL Server 2016

But if are running your application on SQL Server 2016 and later version of SQL Server, you can use [string_split function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/split-string-function-in-sqlserver-2016.aspx) in your stored procedure code

One last note, if you don't have a complex logic behind, just for splitting string parameters instead of using a stored procedure you can use a table valued UDF (user defined function)